# SQL - Methods of storing intermediate sign-up information for users

Tags: database, database-design, registration, two-factor-authentication

I am designing a Node + MySQL backend for a service that requires two-factor authentication to be set up for all users as a part of the sign-up process. Users first submit a primary phone number and password (with the phone number being used for sign-in), upon which the server sends them an SMS with a six-digit code. Only after they enter the code is their account fully created.

This poses the problem of how to store data for users in the intermediate state after entering username/password but before verifying the code. Such "pending users" will not be shown in searches, do not need to store all the data a regular user would, and will be deleted after a few days if never verified. Furthermore, since every user must enable TFA to fully sign up, there will be orders of magnitude more users than "pending users". Thus, it does not seem sensible to me to have all users simply store an "isVerified" flag. I am familiar with SQL on a technical level but have no experience designing databases for production, and I am wondering what alternate mechanisms I should consider to solve the aforementioned.

My current idea is to have a separate table of pending users, having only those columns necessary to store intermediate signup information. When a user verifies, a row is created in the real user table, the signup information is copied over, and the corresponding is row deleted from the pending users table. However, this makes it somewhat ugly to ensure that the primary phone numbers are unique across both tables (which is an additional requirement of the service).

What methods/techniques should I consider to improve my solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can store this data same way as store session information on server.